# how can i optimize this query of Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

how can optimize this query without a **for **loop?

i have some df with more than 40 columns, so i want to get the less time possible.

Thanks!

This is my code

```
        for x in range(0, len(df.columns)):
            df[f"len{x}"] = df.iloc[:, x].astype("string").str.len()
```

i want the length of any row of any column on my df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop in this case isn't that bad. You can do without a for loop like this, however:

```
df = df.join(df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.len())
               .add_prefix('len')
            )
```